# How can I build WebSharper on Mono 3.0 on Mac?

Tags: f#, mono, xbuild, websharper

WebSharper looks interesting, and Mono 3.0 is just out with F# 3.0.  Apparently xbuild can build some MSBuild projects.  Straightforward attempt at building a WebSharper clone on mono fails since FSharpHome is unclear.  What's a good way to define it and other stuff to try further?

Comment: "fails because FSharpHome is unclear"? You're being much more unclear, please just copy+paste the god-damn error :)